# KVM-Guest does not boot: qemudParsePCIDeviceStrs

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have a Server running Ubuntu 10.10 Server-Edition kvm, and libvirt (both ubuntu-native packages)
HDD-Partitioning was done with LVM. Then I created some VMs with Virt-Manager and assigned LVM-Volumes to the VMs.

Now the VMs do not boot. Virt-Manager shows a CPU-Usage of 100% for this Guest and the VNC-Connection states

> Booting from Hard Disk

The VM-specific logfiles do not show any abnormality only syslog shows a warning

> warning : qemudParsePCIDeviceStrs:1422 : Unexpected exit status '1', qemu probably failed

What can I do to find the error?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try stopping AppArmor "sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop; sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown"

then restarting the VM!

Comment: this also didn't work. I found out, that creating new VMs is no problem. They run as they should. So I suspect Virt-Manager of having done something wrong with my old VM's. I used Virt-Manager to reorder the Disk-Positions and after that nothing worked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try switching the disk type, e.g. from virtio to ide.  You can `virsh dumpxml > guestname.xml`, edit the dump file to make the change, destroy and undefine the guest, then create from the edited dump file.

Comment: As an aside, the guest logfiles have yet to provide me really helpful information when troubleshooting a qemu/kvm problem.  This might just be me, but it's one of my few complaints w/ KVM.

Comment: I already had the disk type set to SCSI instead of virtio.

Comment: I'd still switch it to IDE (or even to virtio) to see if it makes a difference.  Also, how are the physical disks composing the LVM volumes connected?  Are they SATA, running through a PCI/x SATA card by chance?  That's one setup I've seen similar (though not identical) errors from.

Comment: lspci | grep SATA shows me an Intel onboard SATA-Controller.
My current config file: http://pastebin.com/K8DDtqi5

Comment: using virtio I get this error: "error: internal error process exited while connecting to monitor: PCI: devfn 24 not available for rtl8139, in use by virtio-blk-pci". 
using ide does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever restart the server after installing libvirt-bin and/or kvm? I have no idea why, but it solved the problem in our case.

Comment: Yes I did. But it didn't help.

Comment: I finally ended up creating a new config with VirtManager with the proper disk-order, setting the disk type to SCSI, reloaded the profile and now it works like a charme.

Answer (score 0):

I just had exacly same problem after increasing VM memory resources via virt-manager:

```
warning : qemudParsePCIDeviceStrs:1422 : Unexpected exit status '1'
qemu probably failed
```

sitting in my `/var/log/messages.log` after trying to start VM.
I could not start VM. Since:

```
sudo service libvirt-bin stop
sudo service libvirt-bin start
```

didn't work on Debian stable 64 I solved this issue with:

```
ps -ef | grep libvirtd
sudo kill -9 31416
sudo service libvirt-bin start
ps -ef | grep libvirtd
```

and then:

```
sudo virsh start SomeOS
```

I think this is related to inaccesible volume or VM disk image.